# Vega-lite heatmap add text to a variable

Tags: elasticsearch, heatmap, vega, vega-lite

```
"data": {
"values": [
  {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0},
  {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 1},
  {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 5},
  {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 10},
  {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 16},
  {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 1},
  {"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 2},
  {"x": 2, "y": 1, "z": 5},
  {"x": 3, "y": 1, "z": 10},
  {"x": 5, "y": 1, "z": 26}
]},
```

How to add text to a variable, so like "AVG:"?
[image]

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-i1SxxcgSdTsV18-Z7dyWdpmjwAGVGOUvYEyj4jtJ-ru5QqlYW4o2oKfqYfm1bWh2zJTsY2bXtq2dWsbndT0yQAR1YJFzWic0qB0as0Qwf8oDoVxDDtFdyW4MtY0PRJkkDdhI3gVNN2yBiwE3aEgiAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculate transform to create specifically-formatted text to display in a text mark. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAB5kAMANFAJ5OuQBeTAvsyrVaDVAEYuHVCyi9xAoRhFkATJM6yyAVgXUa9Veulc5YMY117lqACxGwMnmTEA2S8IPH2zk8-dLPM3sJTVQVf31RMDVvcV9UHUE9NECAZmD4swskq0CtDNDot0UAXSpLSHgAJ1gAO2IAMwB7KoBbMkphRUxYAHNeqsJehEIO2iaABzJIVsI6yC4GgEtCXGhp3i5YUlQnPhKc6kgBpvwJgCMpCgN1Mup-WgBjPEf8XBHpgHJYLF7UT7AAGowHB4PhWgA6TZQbYbSB8KgHKgzWBVADW03ghDo8AWyMItUeTWgS1qvTI6AwgVoy1W612DC48DYE1GuxaJNqeHhh1iKVpa2mHCZLLZUA5pO5-kq2NxqBpK0Fu2hlVF01qTVaktw8PKOUgAHcltB4AALMipRgsZGmwhLXqmuVZRggPhAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 1},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 5},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 10},
      {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 16},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 1},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 2},
      {"x": 2, "y": 1, "z": 5},
      {"x": 3, "y": 1, "z": 10},
      {"x": 5, "y": 1, "z": 26}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [{"op": "mean", "field": "z", "as": "z"}],
      "groupby": ["x", "y"]
    },
    {"calculate": "'avg: ' + datum.z", "as": "z"}
  ],
  "mark": "text",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "ordinal"},
    "text": {"field": "z", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "width": 300,
  "height": 100
}
```

[image]